# Gallery Crop Image is not working in Android 7

Tags: android, image, crop

I have create one app in which I'm opening the gallery and after selecting the image we should crop that image and display in imageview but the problem is that in Android 7 device crop is not supported error message is coming.

Even ever permission is giving in run-time and manifest for camera and read/write external and internal storage

In Manifest:

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.activity.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

In xml/provider_paths

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-path name="images" path="."/>
</paths>
```

In MainActivity:-

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_GALLERY) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            performCrop(selectedImage);
        } else if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE) {
            if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
                //save in sdcard and display in imageview
            }
        }
    }
}


private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "Img_" + timeStamp;
    File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/Img");
    File file=new File(storageDir,imageFileName+".png");
    return file;
}


private void performCrop(Uri picUri) {
    try {
        Uri contentUri;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > M) {
            contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(mContext, "com.activity.provider", createImageFile());
            //TODO:  Permission..
           getApplicationContext().grantUriPermission("com.android.camera", contentUri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        } else {
            contentUri = picUri;
        }

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image");

        cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        cropIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("scale", false);
        cropIntent.putExtra("circleCrop", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 3);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        //display an error message
        ToastManager.toast(mContext, "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In LogCat:-

```
7-06 11:04:10.053 2308-5222/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.android.camera.action.CROP dat=content://com.ripple.activity.provider/Images/Ripple/Image/2017-07-06 11:04:10.046Ripple.jpg typ=image flg=0x3 (has extras)} from uid 10238 on display 0
07-06 11:04:10.230 2308-2798/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.picker.external.ExternalPickerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2067 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:896 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2094 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:575 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:501 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked:303 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked:704 
07-06 11:04:10.468 2308-5194/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.picker.external.ExternalPickerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2067 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:896 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1457 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2531 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2489 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2358 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2349 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193 
07-06 11:04:10.495 2308-4312/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.picker.impl.PickerActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2067 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:896 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1457 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2531 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2489 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2358 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2349 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193 
07-06 11:04:10.500 23080-23080/? I/CastMediaRouteProvider: in onDiscoveryRequestChanged: request=DiscoveryRequest{ selector=MediaRouteSelector{ controlCategories=[com.google.android.gms.cast.CATEGORY_CAST/8DA7527D] }, activeScan=false, isValid=true }
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is not mandatory in Android, and doesn't have to work. You shouldn't use it as it is present not in all devices.

Comment: @VladMatvienko even removing the com.android.camera.action.CROP still in android 7 device it is not running

Comment: and it is expected behavior, as crop is not mandatory in Android. You shouldn't expect it to work at all. Instead I suggest you to implement your own crop functionality, or use some library.